# Django restframework generic viewset not working with get and get detail views with the same url_path and url_name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

How can I make two views in a `DRF Generic viewset` use the same url_paths and url_names provided the make use of the same or different methods but different `details` value, eg must can both be `Get` methods but would have `details=True` and `details=False` on them

sample code for more clarity;

```
 @action(methods=["get"], detail=False, url_path="list-users", url_name="users")
    def get_users(self, request):
        # code here
```

```
 @action(methods=["get"], detail=True, url_path="users", url_name="users")
    def get_user(self, request, id):

        # code here
```

**get_users** work with this endpoint -> `{{base_url}}/{{prefix}}/users`

**get_user** does not work with -> `{{base_url}}/{{prefix}}/{{user-id}}/users`

but if I change the url_path and url_name to something else eg -> `single-user`

then the endpoint for getting a single user works
-> `{{base_url}}/{{prefix}}/{{user-id}}/single-user`

how can I solve this to make the users and user have the same url_name and url_path because the actions have detail as `False`(users) and `True`(user) for both of them respectively

`NB; Also please note that this viewset does not make use of any model`

Comment: `url_name` needs to be unique per view

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, DRF actually has Routing additional HTTP methods for extra actions, which can be viewed here;
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions